# How to update all the TypeID based on the length of the AccountNum in an embedded array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update the TypeId based on the AccountNum length.

If the AccountNum length is 4 TypeId should be updated to A1.

If the AccountNum length is 5 TypeId should be updated to A2.

Similarly,If the AccountNum length is 6 TypeId should be updated to A3.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5770cf084e51b91816094201"),
    "Organization" : ABC,

    "Employees" : [
        {
            "EmpId":1,
            "TypeID" : "A",
            "AccountNum" : 54556

        },
        {
            "EmpId":2,
            "TypeID" : "A",
            "AccountNum" : 545565

        },
        {
            "EmpId":3,
            "TypeID" : "A",
            "AccountNum" : 54556567

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: add one field that store length like length: 4

Comment: I'm not authorized to add the field for the specified data model

Comment: have you tried model.update({'Employees.AccountNum':'54556.length == 5'})

Comment: try model.update({$where:"this.Employees.AccountNum.length == 5"})

Comment: Can you please edit the code over here

Comment: try this code: model.update({$where:"this.Employees.AccountNum.length == 4"},{'$set': {
    'Employees.$.TypeID': 'A1'
}}, function(err,data) {})

Comment: refer this link also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/5xuchL9dU6w

Comment: Is "AccounNum" always between 4 and 6? If not what would you like to do for when AccountNum < 4 or > 6?

Answer (score 2):

Not the best of solutions currently as you need a mechanism to loop through a collection and for each document, loop the embedded array, to identify each `AccountNum` field length using a `switch` or `if else` condition. Within that
inner loop you set a new variable that holds the new type id based on the account number length. You can then update the collection in that same loop.

This whole operation has `O(nm)` complexity where `n` is the number of documents in the collection and `m` is the max `Employees` array size.

The following example illustrates this approach:

```
db.collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.Employees.forEach(function(emp){
        var newTypeID, num = emp.AccountNum;
        switch (true) {
            case (num < 10000):
                newTypeID = "A1";
                break;
            case (num >= 10000 && num < 100000):
                newTypeID = "A2";
                break;
            case (num >= 100000 && num < 1000000):
                newTypeID = "A3";
                break;
            default:
                newTypeID = "A";
                break;
        }

        db.collection.update(
            { "_id": doc._id, "Employees.AccountNum": emp.AccountNum },
            { "$set": { "Employees.$.TypeID": newTypeID } }
        );
    });
});
```

---

For larger collections you will notice a decrease in performance. A better approach would be to utilize the new **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods)** API to update the collection in bulk. This is efficient because it doesn't send every update request to the server as you iterate but just once in every say 500 ordered operations, which is faster:

```
var bulkOps = [];
db.collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {    
    doc.Employees.forEach(function(emp){
        var newTypeID, num = emp.AccountNum;

        switch (true) {
            case (num < 10000):
                newTypeID = "A1";
                break;
            case (num >= 10000 && num < 100000):
                newTypeID = "A2";
                break;
            case (num >= 100000 && num < 1000000):
                newTypeID = "A3";
                break;
            default:
                newTypeID = "A";
                break;
        }

        bulkOps.push({
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": doc._id, "Employees.AccountNum": emp.AccountNum },
                "update": {
                    "$set": { "Employees.$.TypeID": newTypeID }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // Send update request once in 500 batched operations only
    if (bulkOps.length % 500 === 0) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
        bulkOps = [];
    }
});

// Clear the remaining queue
if (bulkOps.length > 0) db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Comment: I thing there is an alternative using the `$switch`  new in the upcoming release of MongoDB with `$map` or `$cond` with `$map`

Comment: @Styvane Yes, you are correct; the ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10689 brought about the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot chridam

Comment: Yeah, It helped me. Is there any method in mongodb which calculates the length of the integer field ?

Comment: @dev777 With the current version I'm afraid not. But with the next release `3.3` there should be a [`$switch`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10689) operator with the aggregation framework where you can check for the length after converting the integer field using the [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower) operator on the numeric field.